# Dataweave passing varaible to url mulesoft

Tags: if-statement, request, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

I'm trying pass the queryParams dynamically to request depending from user what put in postman.
Here is the transform message with variable name jql (this variable I would like then pass in url)

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" >
            <ee:message>
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="queryParams" ><![CDATA[
{
    "demo" : attributes.queryParams['demo'] default "",
        "demo2": attributes.queryParams['demo2'] default "",
         "demo3" :attributes.queryParams['demo3'] default ""
}
                
]]></ee:set-variable>
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message"  >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="jql" ><![CDATA[
if(vars.queryParams.demo != null and vars.queryParams.demo2 == null and vars.queryParams.demo3 == null)
    "demo= " ++ vars.queryParams.demo 
else if(vars.queryParams.demo2 != null and vars.queryParams.demo3 == null and vars.queryParams.demo == null)
    "demo2 = " ++ vars.queryParams.demo2 
else if(vars.queryParams.demo != null and vars.queryParams.demo2 != null and vars.queryParams.demo3 == null )
"demo= " ++ vars.queryParams.demo ++ " and demo2 = " ++ vars.queryParams.demo2 

]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request"  config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/demo/search">
            <http:query-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "jql" : vars.jql
}]]]></http:query-params>
        </http:request>
```

And for example if user put only parameter demo I would like only this "demo = demo" etc.

In this case I got 400 like this:

```
Message               : HTTP GET on resource 'https://demo/search' failed: bad request (400).
Element               : searchForIssuesUsingJQL/processors/2 @ jira:jira.xml:160 (Request)
Element DSL           : <http:request method="GET"
 doc:name="Request"  config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="demo/search">
<http:query-params>#[output application/java
---
{
    "jql" : vars.jql
}]</http:query-params>
</http:request>
Error type            : HTTP:BAD_REQUEST
```

Comment: Can you share what you would like the query params to look like? What you are setting up will look like `jql=demo{encodedequals}demo`

Comment: My url should looks like this : /demo/search?jql=demo = demo  and demo2 = demo2  AND demo3 = demo3
But I don't want have always three filter. That's why I try use if depend what I put in postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a good way to implement it and it doesn't even cover all possible cases. Better make it dynamic. Let's convert vars.QueryParams into a list for easier manipulation and then reduce it into a single strings, adding " and " to separate elements when the accumulator is not empty:

```js
vars.queryParams
    filterObject (sizeOf($) > 0)
    pluck ((value, key, index) -> {k: key, v:value})
    map ($.k ++ "=" ++ $.v)
    joinBy  " and "
```

With this method you don't even need to know if it contains a specific string.

Comment: Thanks it seems good. I was trying this but in vars.jql I got "demo= and demo2=Test and demo3=" and I got 400. I don't know why

Comment: Do you mean using my script? What is the value of `vars.queryParams`?

Comment: Yes when using your script. I think because I have deafult "" for each queryParams.

Comment: I solve it using nested if and it's working. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't know values could be empty. I added a filter to exclude those from the transformation. Remember that DataWeave is a functional language and has functions that operate over arrays or object that provide more elegant solutions than using if, and make the code much more clearer.

Comment: I updated my answer to avoid using if as an example of alternatives.